# Ignore a specific test using Django

Tags: python, django

I'm aware of how to run a specific test class with django : `python manage.py test MyApp.MyTestClass`.

What I'd like to do is the opposite : run every tests except one in particular.
To my mind, this would look like this : `python manage.py test --ignore=MyApp.MyTestClass`
Is there a simple way to do so ?

EDIT : An extra bonus would be to still be able to run the test manually (using the first command).

Answer (score 19):

The `test` command has no built-in ignore option.

But you could use the `@skip` or `@skipIf` decorator in the class you want to exlude: http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html#unittest.skipIf

```
 import unittest

 @unittest.skip("skip the test")
 class MyTestClass(TestCase):
 ...
```

Comment: I added an extra need wich is not easily satisfied with this solution (as far as I can tell).

Comment: skip works on the class, but skipIf does not. You have to use skipIf on each test function. This is still a good way of conditionally skipping tests though.

Answer (score 4):

Test command does not have ignore option by default. You can try [django-ignoretests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ignoretests/0.3.2). You can install it using

```
pip install django-ignoretests
```

You can ignore apps by including them in `IGNORE_TESTS` as given below:

```
IGNORE_TESTS = (
    # Apps to ignore. example : 'django.contrib.auth',
)
```